# Can VBA add to my workbook title and then save it back to the same folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automatically rename and save my workbook to the folder/subfolder I pulled it from once my macro finishes running. Once my report has been filtered initially by the macro, I want a new line to add the word "Worked" to the current title and then save the workbook to exactly the same folder I pulled the unworked report from so I can see which reports have been filtered already.

The line I am using right now as a simple test of the Save As function is

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Filename = "Worked"
```

But when I run that, it doesn't even save to the folder I initially pulled it from, and obviously doesn't address the naming issue at all. I've tried looking into alternate naming commands but everything I have found tells me how I can set a new name rather than just add a word to the end of the current name.

Comment: Hint: `ThisWorkbook.Path & Filename = "Worked"` returns a path with a boolean (True/False) at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `SaveCopyAs' - the original workbook is still open after saving the copy.

To add "worked" just replace the file extension by "worked.xlsm"

```vb
Public Sub saveCopy(wb As Workbook)

With wb
    .Save
    
    Dim newFilename As String
    newFilename = Replace(.FullName, ".xlsm", " worked.xlsm")
    
    .SaveCopyAs newFilename
End With

End Sub
```

You can call the sub e.g. by `saveCopy ActiveWorkbook`.